# Can I substitute Win 10 with Ubuntu desktop, without losing my data?

Tags: system-installation, backup, windows-10, switch-user

I'm thinking about switching from Win 10 to Ubuntu desktop. The primary concern is the safety of my data, of course. **Can I simply substitute Win 10 with Ubuntu, erase everything in the C drive, and keep F&G drives intact?** Would be great if no need for extra efforts to backup a lot.

Also, how is Ubuntu doing with the "outer" world, if I may ask people who have more experience? I mean, you always see concrete solutions for Windows and Mac, but rarely for Linux unless it's an IT-related topic. For example, the internet was recently upgraded in my building, and a lot of us are having problems registering the new thing. The provider explicitly say that they can absolutely solve the problem for Win/Mac users but no guanrantee for Linux users, which sounds upsetting.

Any other suggestions for a Linux beginner? Appreciate it if I could avoid some stupid mistakes.

Comment: Please try VirtualBox. The Windows version is easy to install and a web search will show your simple instructions on how to create a Ubuntu VM. You will be able to access your data on your Windows machine and you will be free to explore Linux while being able to return to the Windows world when you want the comfort of the familiar.

Comment: @StephenBoston That sounds great! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! *"Would be great if no need for extra efforts to backup a lot"*. IMO, I would suggest; if you have the means, simply backup your data, just because it's a *always a good practice*. You will feel unconcerned of what happens to your computer/OS, regardless of which is it. You can also experience linux without a VM. The USB installer is a live OS, you can tinker all you want without installing anything.

Comment: *"Any other suggestions for a Linux beginner? "* Have in mind that linux has its problems, like any other OS, but I would say that you don't feel discouraged If you encounter some. Linux is awesome and fun, and has communities like this that are willing to help. The learning curve can be a *little* steep for *some* people so used to windows (and mac), but once you get to understand a couple of things, you may fall in love with it ️.

Comment: For example, I recently changed my [desktop environment](https://itsfoss.com/best-linux-desktop-environments/), just beacause I *want* and I *can* with linux. You don't have that kind of options in windows or mac, you are stuck with what they shipped.

Comment: Ubuntu is NOT a drop-in replacement for Windows. It uses a different filesystem. Many features work quite differently. It's mult-user. Permissions work very differently. Managing the software on your system is completely different. And *many Windows applications don't work*. This site is littered with the tears of frustrated Windows power-users who did not realize just how different Linux is before the committed. This site is also home to many, many folks who respected the differences, climbed that learning curve, and happily use both daily.

Comment: Do not get rid of Windows, rather, set up a dual-boot environment. You'll need Windows to run some Windows-only apps, and things like BIOS/firmware updates.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Yeah I totally agree with you, with everything. Our univ labs use Ubuntu, so I kinda have tried it already and I like it. With Windows everything is a black box, and very often I have no ideas what just happened and my laptop just become suspiciously slow...

Comment: @user535733 Thank you very much! I'll keep that in mind! I like this Linux community alreay haha

Comment: @heynnema Thanks! Could you give me an example of Windows-only apps? I'm trying to make a list of what I can't do after abandoning Windows. BTW, things I must have include RStudio, Python 3, Git, Google Chrome, Foxit, Evernote, and WeChat. I hope they would get on with Ubuntu

Comment: Windows-only apps... BIOS/firmware updates for sure. You mention some other apps that may be Windows-only. Python 3, GIT, Google Chrome all work in Ubuntu. You'll have to research the others, and see if there are Linux equivalents. Really... don't abandon Windows... just don't use it unless you have to.

Comment: Many newer systems now support UEFI updates from Linux. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist & 
https://fwupd.org/vendorlist
And list seems to be growing regularly. I would not consider buying a new system that is not on list, even though many of those vendors still may say they do not support Linux. You also can find nearly equivalent apps in Linux. Some even are better than Windows versions, some about equal, and some may not be as good, but functional. Biggest issues often are proprietary vendor software that only works in Windows.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks!

Comment: @oldfred Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never loosing your data, because you have, at any time, **a good backup copy of your data**, preferably on multiple locations.

If you do not have any backup copy of your data, then that means that you do not *care* about these data. It is then not important if they are overwritten when installing a new operating system.

That said, for your case, for sure **other partitions than the one you are installing to will stay intact during installation**. You indicate wanting to substitute Windows 10, so you will be installing Ubuntu on the partition known under Windows as the C: drive. Your partitions know as F: and G: will be untouched. If the file system of these partitions is in good health, you will be able to access these files from within Ubuntu.

Yet, in the longer term, it is **not good to keep these files on partitions that were formatted from within Windows**, i.e., in the ntfs file system, if you do not have Windows around anymore. Linux can read and write to a Windows ntfs system, but its capabilities to check and repair such a partition are limited. In a scenario where you cannot anymore access an ntfs partition with Windows, you should be convert that partition to a fully linux supported file system, typically ext4. And that will also require whipping the disk, so before proceeding, you must make sure that your backup is up to date. You will need it to put your data back.

**Bottom line**: Make sure you have good backup copies anytime, and then you do not need to worry about the data when installing a new operating system.

Comment: This was pretty much my migration path: first a dual boot with my data on ntfs drives, then eventually converted them to ext4, and got rid of the windows.  Welcome to ubuntu!

Comment: This said, there are plenty of calls for help here and on other SE sites from people who installed to the wrong partition, so beware. Backups, backups and backups. Another safe solution is to get a new disk and an external disk adapter, replace the disk in the PC, install Ubuntu, put the previous disk in the external adapater and copy the files. If dissatisfied with Linux, you go back by just swapping the disks. If satisfied, you just a got an external disk for your backups.

Comment: @xenoid yeah that sounds like a safe adventure haha

Comment: Thank you very much! I just learned a lot

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, this is just a conceptual outline helping you to get the general concept. Once you understand better, it is much easier to find your way, and to find more specific solutions to specific problems. Success!